# Problem with sculpting, using graphics monitor

Tags: transforms, customization, sculpting, error

So I have this graphics drawing monitor **Huion Kamvas**, that I'm trying to use with the blender sculpting, and I am getting this weird issue. Whenever I try to put the first stroke on my object, everything seems fine, but once I rotate or pan the view, the object is acting like I'm not pressing on it at all, although my cursor is following my pen tip movement... and then again, if I rotate or pan my view once more, it comes back to normal. I have to repeat this over and over, and it gets quite frustrating.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like it could very easily be a problem with your monitor or how it is set up (how it registers input, etc.). As far as I know as well, Huion products can sometimes have issues with blender as well, for reasons I don't know. If you don't get an answer on here soon I would definitely recommend contacting Huion to see if they can diagnose the issue.

Comment: You might consider downloading the latest driver update for your Huion Kanvas. You can get it from Huion site. Ensure to select the correct driver.

Comment: After you observe the issue, while it's still active, can you make strokes with another mouse/trackball/trackpad? I ask because I wonder if there's some modifier key that's stuck (not reading a key-up signal for instance).

Also, while the issue is active, try tapping once on each of ctrl, alt, and shift (individually), and see if that fixes the issue on the display. Might confirm the modifier key being stuck.

Comment: Hi, have you updated to the latest drivers for the Huion and the latest Blender?

Comment: Isn't it for but report or is it specific hardware issue? Anyway two years later and zero details from OP.